# MongoDB. Замедляется поиск

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Имеется табличная БД с логами, которые нужно перелопатить день за днем и собрать агрегированные данные в MongoDB в одну коллекцию.
Сервер на 8гб оперативки. SSD. По камням не знаю, простите.

Суть такая: в процессе работы, мы записываем в коллекцию простые документы вида

```
{_id : <наш уникальный айди>, array : [1,2,3]}
```

В документе может поменяться только array.
Т.е. скрипт смотрит - если есть документ, то апдтейтит его. Если нет, то создает новый.

Происходит это асинхронно на node.js в 10 000 запросов за раз. 
После записи батча, стартует следующий.

Проблема В том, что чем больше коллекция, тем дольше осуществляется чтение и запись документов. Это логично, но не в сотни же раз.

Т.е. когда у нас коллекция имеет размер 100-200к документов, всё пишется  и читается моментально.
Работа с коллекцией из 3 млн документов замедляется в 2 и более раз.
А 9 млн уже не могут даже прочитаться. на один гет запрос уходит по 4 секунды, не говоря уже о записи.
При этом так же заметно, что иногда запись или чтение приостанавливается вообще. Операция записи очередного батча может провисеть на 12% или 90% до  10 минут. После чего продолжается дальше как ни в чем не бывало.

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано? в какую сторону копать.

Коллекция индексирована только по полю _id. По нему же и осуществляется поиск документов.

Сервер новый. Только поставили на него БД с одной коллекцией что бы проверить в лабораторных условиях.
До этого такая же работа наблюдалась и просто на локальной машине с HDD